# Why the buttons of slider is changing their position whenever their are one,three or more rows of thumbnail?

Tags: html, jquery, css, laravel, slider

```
<div class="row">

               <?php
               $orderlist = null;
               $orderactive = 'active';

               $image_file = null;

               if ($car_files->count() > 0) {
                  $x = 0;
                  foreach ($car_files as $r) {
                     $x++;
                     $image = public_path('car_uploads') . '/no-car-image-placeholder.png';
                     $image_file = $r->file_up_name;
                     if (is_file(public_path('car_uploads') . '/' . $image_file)) {
                        $image = url('car_uploads/' . $image_file);
                     }

                     {
                        $cols = 'col-md-img';
                     }
                     echo '<div class="' . $cols . ' mb-2">
                    <img src="' . $image . '" id="' . $x . '" class="thumbimg allclick" style="border-radius:5px;max-height:120px;"/>
                    </div>';


                     $orderlist .= '<li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="' . $x . '" class="' . $orderactive . ' carosel_circle"></li>';
                     $orderactive = '';
                  }
               } else {
                  $image = public_path('car_uploads') . '/no-car-image-placeholder.png';
                  echo '
                <div class="col-3">
                <img src="' . $image . '" />
                </div>';
               }
               ?>
               <div id="custom-ol">
                  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                     <?= $orderlist; ?>
                  </ol>
               </div>


            </div>
```

this the divs for slider of thumbnail and its buttons but whenever the row of thumbnails are two they are fine but go up whenever there is one row and go down whenever there is three or more i want to fix it's position up to slider where it looks fine when there are two rows but don't know how the div with id custom-ol are the button kind of sliders this is not getting fixed at one place always change when the row change also i can't change the code due to requirements but wanting to fix this like through html css or bootstrap maybe js or jQuery